# SwiperJS failing Jest unit tests with "Cannot read property ngModule of undefined"

Tags: angular, jestjs, swiper.js, nrwl-nx

I am using Swiper v8 for my Angular v12 project that resides in an Nx monorepo.

To give some context, the Swiper carousel component is declared in a module and exported as one of the *libs* in the project. Let's call it **@mylib/carousel**.

The component Jest tests initially failed with the **"Cannot find module swiper_angular"** error and a quick search in SO suggests a fix like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      ...
      "swiper_angular": ["node_modules/swiper/angular"]
    } 
}
```

I put the code above in tsconfig.base.json file in the repo root alongside other libs alias paths.

The error went away but a new set of errors came in about Unexpected token 'export'.

```
Dev/my-app/node_modules/swiper/angular/swiper_angular.d.ts:5
    export * from './swiper-angular';
    ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

These new errors were showing up in unit tests in the @mylib/carousel lib as well as other apps and libs that were importing the @mylib/carousel.

Further searching suggests using *transformIgnorePattern* syntax in jest.config.js:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
   'node_modules/(?!swiper|ssr-window|dom7)'
]
```

I have tried adding the *transformIgnorePatterns* code into various jest.config.js files but it did not fix the issue entirely. From my observation, there were two outcomes:

1. When I added the line in the @mylib/carousel jest.config.js file, the unit tests passed.
2. When I added the line in other *libs* and *apps* jest.config.js files that are importing the @mylib/carousel, the *Unexpected token export* error was gone but a new error showed up in files that were importing a lib that depended on @mylib/carousel.

```
apps/shop-app/src/app/modules/cart/cart.component.spec.ts
  ● CartComponent › should create

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngModule' of undefined

      at isModuleWithProviders (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:560:38)
      at expandModuleWithProviders (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:553:7)
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Function.get (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:125:25)
      at getNgModuleDef (../../../packages/core/src/render3/definition.ts:745:27)
      at isNgModule (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:564:12)
      at ../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:492:10
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at transitiveScopesFor (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:486:30)
      at setScopeOnDeclaredComponents (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:416:28)
      at Object.flushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible [as ɵflushModuleScopingQueueAsMuchAsPossible] (../../../packages/core/src/render3/jit/module.ts:59:11)
      at TestBedRender3.Object.<anonymous>.TestBedRender3.checkGlobalCompilationFinished (../../../packages/core/testing/src/r3_test_bed.ts:445:7)
      at TestBedRender3.Object.<anonymous>.TestBedRender3.resetTestingModule (../../../packages/core/testing/src/r3_test_bed.ts:261:10)
      at Function.Object.<anonymous>.TestBedRender3.resetTestingModule (../../../packages/core/testing/src/r3_test_bed.ts:194:26)
      at ../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_hooks.ts:38:15
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:407:30)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:3765:43)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:406:56)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:167:47)
      at Object.wrappedFunc (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing-bundle.umd.js:4250:34)
```

Appreciate any guidance I can get as I have been spending the entire weekend trying to solve this.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have a similar problem.

Comment: @Nevius Unfortunately no, I had to downgrade to Swiper v6.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error.
These and other issues are also discussed in the github post:
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4315

For me, at least two options worked:

1. Downgrade to version 7.4.1 (from 8.x.x)
2. Be more specific using moduleNameMapper in jest.config:

**Before**

```
    moduleNameMapper: {
        swiper_angular: '<rootDir>/../../node_modules/swiper/angular',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)'],
```

**After**

```
    moduleNameMapper: {
        swiper_angular: '<rootDir>/../../node_modules/swiper/angular/esm2020/swiper_angular.mjs',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)'],
```

Hope this helps!